# HttpClient basic authentication against Web API fails, while browser works as expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication, iis-express

I'm testing my own Web API service, and after adding of

```
[Authorize(Roles = "MyRole")]
```

to the controller, all requests made by `HttpClient` fails with "Unauthorized" (401). Service is hosted in IIS Express with Windows authentication enabled, as suggested [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication).

Client sends appropriate request header:

```
var authHeaderParameter = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("MyUser:MyPassword"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authHeaderParameter);
```

The same request (at least, the same URI and credentials) made from browser works as expected and returns data.
Fiddler shows, that browser sends "Proxy-Authorization" request header, and doesn't send any "Authorization".

What am I doing wrong?
How to fix request using `HttpClient`?

**UPD**.

This doesn't help too:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    UseProxy = false
};

var client = new HttpClient(handler, true)
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress)
};
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are sitting in an enterprise behind a corporate proxy server that requires authentication to get to the internet?  If so, there is a separate mechanism for providing proxy credentials.  See HttpClientHandler.Proxy

Comment: As you are trying to hit a local service, you might want to look at this also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.useproxy(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @DarrelMiller: I'm in corporate network, but both server and client on the same (local) machine.

Comment: Try setting the UseProxy to false.

Comment: @DarrelMiller: base address is "http://localhost...". AFAIK, this means, that proxy should be bypassed. Anyway, I've tried `UseProxy = false` without success.

Comment: Can you make requests to some other internal or external services that don't require authentication?

Comment: @DarrelMiller: yes, I can. Moreover, if I remove `[Authorize]` from controller I mentioned, everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the problem was located inside IIS Express settings.
I'll post this answer and shall add "VS 2015" tag into question, because it might be helpful.

Thanks to @swiley, [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and [npcap](https://github.com/nmap/npcap) (the last is needed to capture loopback interface traffic via WireShark).

Inspecting response headers, that were sent to web browser, I've found, that 401 responses contain `Autorization: NTLM` headers. Since browser automatically handles this case, it sends current NTLM credentials in further requests and get the requested data. My `HttpClient` code does not, and, actually, must not handle `NTLM`.

**Prerequisites.**

First of all, this is VS 2015 and my Web API project uses IIS Express for hosting, which is the default setting. Non-default here is that I've changed port to the constant value:

[image]

The second, IIS express in **VS 2015** stores its configuration in `%SolutionDir%\.vs\config\applicationhost.config` file. Note, that this was changed from previous versions.

The third.
Project properties, available on F4 key press, are very limited, and, in fact, you're just modifying the same `applicationhost.config` from above:

[image]

The fourth, [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication) post doesn't helps:

> To enable Basic authentication using IIS, set the authentication mode
>   to "Windows" in the Web.config of your ASP.NET project:

While this will work with "mature" IIS, Visual Studio + IIS express just ignore these settings.

**The solution.**

1. Open `%SolutionDir%\.vs\config\applicationhost.config` in text editor.
2. Find first `<authentication>` tag.
3. Under it, find `<basicAuthentication enabled="false" />`, and change `enabled` to `true`.
4. Save file.
5. Restart Web application.

Note, that properties you can see by pressing F4 are stored under `<location path="YourProjectName">` tag.

By default, it has sub-tag `authentication`, but without `basicAuthentication`:

```
<authentication>
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
</authentication>
```

If solution has more that one IIS Express-hosted project with custom authentication settings, one should add `basicAuthentication` into project-related section instead of first `<authentication>` tag, which is global config per solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would post a comment but my reputation is too low, in the past I've had this problem when the server sent back an http redirect and the http library automatically sent back my request without the custom header data. I think the request or response object will have a uri field if this happens, you can also disable automatic redirection handling. I ended up figuring all this out using wire shark though and I highly suggest you do that next.

Comment: That's a good suggestion.  The redirect URL will be in the Location header if that is the case.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks again. This is not redirection problem, but inspecting of response headers with WireShark really had helped me.